# Conditional statements depending on message box choices

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, messagebox

How do I catch the message box selection of a user? I'm not sure if "catch" is the right term, since that term might only refer to errors, but I hope you know what I mean. If there is a message box with "Ok" and "Cancel" as button/selection options, then how do I make my program run conditional statements depending on the user's selection?

Comment: Seems to me you on the wrong website. Here we give solutions to problems, not tutorials on basic language syntax.

Comment: Ts Ts, my picture says it all - it's a problem for me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the `DialogResult` from the `MessageBox`. Please see small example below. To read & get more info see **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** for more details about this.

```
    Dim Result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you free?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel)

    Select Case Result
        Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes
            'Do something when yes is selected.
        Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No
            'Do something when no is selected.
        Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
            'Do something when cancel is selected.
    End Select
```